# Web Template solution dependency to created sites

Tags: web-template

I would like to deploy a web template which has absolutely no dependency with the created site so that I could retract the web template solution from the farm, and the sites created with it would continue working.

How can I ensure that there is no dependencies between the web template solution package and the created site collections?

I am trying to only provision content: Add a new Default.aspx (I'm creating the web template from STS#0), add a master page, add list instances and web parts.

Comment: This seems like a strange requirement. Why exactly do you need to do this? Is it to mitigate migration risks?

Comment: Yes and possible O365 migration later on. Also, I only want to use web templates for provisioning content, so being always in the future dependent on the solutions seems a big price to pay. The cost of versioning the templates is also likely to increase pretty much I think.

Comment: Also, I'm kind of looking things from the perspective of remote provisioning; Microsoft seems to be pushing its customers there and it also would be my primary choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a site using a Web Template there is no dependency from that site to the Web Template that created it, that's one of the major differences between Site Templates and Web Templates.

BUT the Web Template may use custom features which then create a dependency between the Site and the solution(s) containing these features. These dependencies may come from the fact that the features contains `<Module>` elements which provisions files and the site then becomes dependent on these files existing in the file system as long as the files are uncustomized or they may contain List definitions.

If you want a custom page and master page, but with no dependency to the feature, then you have to create the page and master page using code.